# Consume WSDL that requires action level authorization in C#

Tags: c#, soap, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, service-provider

I'm attempting to consume a 3rd party WSDL. I have added it as a service reference. I initalize the client and query paramaters like this:

```
var ltRequest = new SearchEmailAddressStatus 
            {
                 EmailAddress = emailAddressList.ToArray()
            };
var ltClient = new CommunicationPreferenceServiceClient
             {
                ClientCredentials =
                   {
                       UserName = 
                         {
                             UserName = ltProperties.CompanyCredential.UserName,
                             Password = ltProperties.CompanyCredential.Password
                         }
                     }
              };  
var ltResponse = ltClient.searchEmailAddressStatusWS(ltRequest);
```

After watching the packets in Fiddler, I've noticed the Auth header is never sent to the server. Is there any way to manually insert an authorization header in my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of digging I found the answer. After declaring the client, I used the following code:

```
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(ltClient.InnerChannel))
{
    var reqProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    reqProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " 
             + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
               ltClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + 
               ltClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));

    OperationContext.Current
        .OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = reqProperty;

    var ltResponse = ltClient.searchEmailAddressStatusWS(ltRequest);
}
```

I believe this is the least-dirty means of getting a customized header inside wsdl request. If someone has a better method, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Nah that's pretty much how I do it. I hope you are using transport level security, given you are passing credentials.